# Correspondence for Artin characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a local field and $G_K$ be the absolute Galois group of $K$. An **Artin character** is any continuous group homomorphism $G_K \to \mathbb{C}^*$ whose image is finite.

**Correspondence**: Now I would like to understand why each Artin character $\chi$ corresponds to a unique pair $(F/K, \bar{\chi})$ where $F/K$ is a cyclic Galois extension (i.e. its Galois group is cyclic) and $\bar{\chi}: \operatorname{Gal}(F/K) \to \langle\xi_n\rangle \subset \mathbb{C}^*$ is an isomorphism where $\xi_n$ is an $n$-th primitive root of unity.

I know that every finite subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is cyclic. Therefore the image of an Artin character is generated by a primitive root of unity, i.e. $\rho(G_K) = \langle \xi_n \rangle$. To get an isomorphism, I assume that we must take the preimage of $\langle \xi_n \rangle$ under $\rho$, and since $\langle \xi_n \rangle$ is finite, the preimage is a finite cyclic subset of $G_K$. Why does it has to be a finite Galois extension then? And why is this extension unique?

For instance, if $K=\mathbb{Q}_3$ we can find two different extensions $F = \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{3})$ and $F' = \mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt{2})$ (they are different because $F/K$ is totally ramified whereas $F'/K$ is unramified). Say we have two isomorphisms $\bar{\chi}: \operatorname{Gal}(F/K) \to \{\pm 1\}$ and $\bar{\chi}': \operatorname{Gal}(F'/K) \to \{\pm 1\}$. How would $\chi: G_K \to \mathbb{C}^*$ and $\chi': G_K \to \mathbb{C}^*$ look like?

It would be nice if you could answer my question and verify my reasoning before. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I would think the idea is that $F$ is the field of invariants of the kernel of the group homomorphism $f:G_K\to\Bbb{C}^*$. In other words, the usual Galois correspondence between $F$ and $\operatorname{Ker} f$. Remember that $f$ is continuous, so its kernel is closed, and hence corresponds cleanly with an intermediate field. The elements of $G_K$ not in the kernel then act non-trivially on $F$. But, a part of Galois theory is that $Gal(F/K)\simeq G_K/G_F\simeq f(G_K)$.

Comment: So in your examples $\chi$ would map all of $G_F$ to $1$, and an element of $G_K$ according to what its restriction to $F$ looks like.

Comment: $\chi$ is a morphism $Gal(\overline{K}/K) \to \mathbb{C}^*$ thus an isomorphism $Gal(L/K)=Gal(\overline{K}/K)/\ker(\chi) \to \langle \xi_n \rangle$ where $L = \overline{K}^{\ker(\chi)}$ and $\langle \xi_n \rangle = Im(\chi)$.

Comment: If $\rho$ is a representaion of $Gal(L/K)$ with $L/K$ normal then $\sigma \mapsto \rho(\sigma|_L)$ is a representation of $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$